# how to prove a inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration, derivatives

I have to prove that if I have $$x'=\sin \left [ 2(x+t) \right ]$$ and $x(t), y(t)$ are two maximal solutions, then 
$$|x(t)-y(t)|\leq |x(t_0) -y(t_0)|e^{2|t-t_0|}$$
I have thought about prove that $$|x'(t)-y'(t)| \leq 2|x-y|$$ with this I know that is enough but how to prove it??
$$\left |\sin \left [2(x+t) \right ]- \sin \left [2(y+t) \right ] \right | \leq 2|x-y|$$ I have thought about the formula of $\sin(a+b)$ but I don't get to anything and about the Taylors development but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I have this I think it's ok:
$$|sin[2(x+t)]-sin[2(y+t)]|=2|sin(\dfrac{2x-2y+2t-2t}{2})cos(\dfrac{2x+2y+4t}{2})=2sen(x-y)cos(x+y+2t)|\leq 2|x-y|$$
using
$$|sin(x-y)|\leq |x-y|$$
is it right???